# New airflow directory created when i run airflow webserver

Tags: airflow

I'm having a few problems with airflow. When I installed airflow and set the airflow home directory to be

```
my_home/Workspace/airflow_home
```

But when I start the webserver a new airflow directory is created

```
my_home/airflow
```

I thought maybe something in the `airflow.cfg` file needs to be changed but I'm not really sure. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: The solution to this problem is [here]. [here]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681213/new-airflow-is-made-on-its-ownairflows-default-directory-other-than-the-airfl/61681374#61681374

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `echo $AIRFLOW_HOME` and see if it the correct path you set

Answer (score 0):

you need to set AIRFLOW_HOME to the directory where you save airflow config file.

if the full path of airflow.cfg file is /home/test/bigdata/airflow/airflow.cfg
just run

`export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/test/bigdata/airflow`

if AIRFLOW_HOME is not set, it will use ~/airflow as default.

you could also write a shell script to start airflow webserver
it might contain lines below

```
source ~/.virtualenvs/airflow/bin/activate  # if your airflow is installed with virtualenv, this is not necessary
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/test/bigdata/airflow  # path should be changed according to your environment
airflow webserver -D  # start airflow webserver as daemon
```