# New Airflow is made on its own(airflow's default directory) other than the airflow that i installed in a specific directory. What is happening?

Tags: installation, airflow

I've installed airflow in a virtual env so prior to installing it, I specified a **directory** in which the install will occur. Installation is done everything works fine without any issues(its the **same terminal** that i used for installation) but if i open a **new terminal**, activate the env and run any airflow command what happens is,a **new airflow get generated** out of no where in its **default airflow location** so the airflow commands no longer **access my airflow and rather access this new one**. 
Even re-installation didn't help.
How is this even possible that at the same time, it works in one terminal but not in other!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you open a new terminal and activate the Virtual Env, `airflow` still does not know where to look for configs until the `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable is set up.

Most likely in your second terminal, you don't have `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable set, hence airflow uses the default `AIRFLOW_HOME` i.e `$HOME/airflow`.

You should set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file so the environment variables are preserved when you use new terminal.